# React handle empty props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, undefined

I want to render an image, whose url I fetch from an API on app start. When I do this react crahses with following message: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'icon' of undefined`.
Whilst `icon` is a property within an object I can access everything else and even the object.

```
class Current extends React.Component {
  render() {
    console.log(this.props.current.condition);
    // Ok, first I write undefined to the console, but then the object
    console.log(this.props.current.condition.icon);
    // BAM. Doomsday.

    return (
      // Beneath me everything is totaly fine.
      <div className="Current">
        <div className="Important">
          <div>
            <img src={this} alt={this} />
            <span>{this.props.current.temp_c}</span>
          </div>
          <h1>{this.props.location.name}, {this.props.location.country}</h1>
          <p>{this.props.location.localtime}</p>
        </div>
        <h1>hey</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Current;
```

I tried juggeling the object with `ComponentWillMount` and `ComponentDiDMount` but it didn't help. How can I access the `icon` property without crashing the application?
**Edit**: Kind of fixed by this:

```
<img 
src={typeof(this.props.current.condition) === 'undefined' ? '' : this.props.current.condition.icon} 
alt={typeof(this.props.current.condition) === 'undefined' ? '' : this.props.current.condition.text} 
/>
```

...but this can't be clean code, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Current extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { current } = this.props
    if ( !(current && current.condition) ) return <span>Loading</span>;

    return (
      // Beneath me everything is totaly fine.
      <div className="Current">
        <div className="Important">
          <div>
            <img src={this} alt={this} />
            <span>{this.props.current.temp_c}</span>
          </div>
          <h1>{this.props.location.name}, {this.props.location.country}</h1>
          <p>{this.props.location.localtime}</p>
        </div>
        <h1>hey</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Current;
```

Comment: Please explain how your code solves the OPs question. This will improve the helpfulness of your question for both the OP and any future visitors.

Comment: It returns the Loading message if `condition` doesn't exist. The code is self explanatory.

Answer (score 2):

try

`src={this.props.current.condition && this.props.current.condition.icon}`

Comment: Using this `&&` syntax is not a good practice. ESLint would bang on you if you run this code of yours through it.

Comment: you could use `this.props.current.condition==null ? "" : this.props.current.condition.icon` if you prefer

Comment: @UtkarshPramodGupta I've used this style for several months. I'm interested in learning best practices to improve my code. I found [ESLint Rules] but do not see one that relates to this syntax. Can you point to the one that supports your claim?

Comment: `==null` will check for null or undefined, and if not use the `.icon`

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to test if a variable is undefined is like this:

```
this.props.current.condition === undefined
```

There is no need to use `typeof()` because `undefined` is a valid value in JavaScript code.

You can simplify this in a condition because `undefined` is already considered "falsy". This means that you can use an `undefined` value directly in an `if` statement. In React, the common idiom is like this:

```
this.props.current.condition && this.props.current.condition.icon
```

This will evaluate to `undefined` if `this.props.current.condition` is `undefined`. Otherwise, it will evaluate to the value of `this.props.current.condition.icon`.

For a deeper understanding, I suggest that you learn about "truthiness" and "falsiness" in JavaScript. I also suggest you learn about boolean operators and short-circuiting.